# how to get string action and controller names from UrlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got

```
public MvcHtmlString(this UrlHelper url)
{
    string controller = //???
    string action = //????
}
```

anybody knows the solution ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. The UrlHelper is used to create Url's, so it does not store an action or controller, you give it data, and it will generate an URL.

Comment: @Gvs you can call <%=Url.Action("Index") %> so you don't have to specify the controller, it means that it knows the controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
string controller = url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
string action = url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
```